# Which is the most efficient nil value?

Tags: performance, go

Hi while doing some exercises I've came across this question...
Lets say you have a map with the capacity of 100,000.
**Which value is the most efficient to fill the whole map in the least amount of time?**

---

I've ran some benchmarks on my own trying out most of the types I could think of and the resulting top list is:

```
Benchmark_Struct-8           200           6010422 ns/op    (struct{}{})
Benchmark_Byte-8             200           6167230 ns/op    (byte = 0)
Benchmark_Int-8              200           6112927 ns/op    (int8 = 0)
Benchmark_Bool-8             200           6117155 ns/op    (bool = false)
```

Example function:

```
func Struct() {
    m := make(map[int]struct{}, 100000)
    for i := 0; i < 100000; i++ {
        m[i] = struct{}{}
    }
}
```

---

As you can see the fastest one *(most of the time)* is type `struct{}{}` - empty struct.

- But why is this the case in **go**?
- Is there a faster/lighter nil or non-nil value?

*- Thank you for your time :)*

Comment: I don't think the time taken to add a lot of empty values to a map which is never used is a common use case. You're basically just testing the machine code used to expand different types of maps. Overall memory usage _might_ be more relevant for most programs if there is any difference at all. I personally like having a bool value so the `, ok` isn't needed to check for a key's existence.

Comment: Theres a situation where this can come in useful but its not that relevant because the speed difference is not that big. Hmm interesting point (regarding bools). Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Theoretically, `struct{}{}` should be the most efficient because it requires no memory. In practice, a) results may vary between Go versions, operating systems, and system architectures; and b) I can't think of any case where maximizing the execution-time efficiency of empty values is relevant.

Comment: I agree its not the most relevant question for Real-Life Apps. But I found it interesting because I was expecting byte=0 to be the fastest. From time to time I like to fiddle around with the language. Thank you for your constructive answer :)

Comment: `byte=0` requires 8 bits of storage `struct{}{}` requires 0.  Managing 8 bits x N occurrences will generally be less efficient than managing 0 bits x N occurrences.

Comment: @Flimzy: since a hashmap doesn't ever want to have full buckets (the const load factor in Go is 6.5), the overhead of buckets almost makes up for any difference between `bool` (which is packed directly into the bucket anyway) and `struct{}`. While there still is a small 5-6% difference in memory usage (at least there was last time I did the math, which was a few releases ago), you can't say that using N `struct{}` values in a map saves you `N` bytes.

Comment: @Jimb that's some interesting information, thank you for sharing. Is there any other type besides `struct{}` that uses 0 bits in go?

Comment: @Mihailo All array types that have 0 length, e.g. `[0]byte`, `[0]int` etc.